Counting monotonic arrays
Let $\mathcal M_d(N)$ denote the collection of functions from $\mathbb N_{0}^d\to\mathbb N_0$ with the following properties:

$f(\mathbf n+\mathbf e_i)\le f(\mathbf n)$ for all $\mathbf n\in \mathbb N_{0}^d$ and all $i\in\{1,\dotsc,d\}$ where $\mathbf e_i$ denotes the standard unit vector in the $i$th direction;
$\sum_{\mathbf n\in\mathbb N_{0}^d}f(\mathbf n)=N$.

I am interested in the asymptotics of $\#\mathcal M_d(N)$. In the case $d=1$, $\#\mathcal M_1(N)$ is the partition function $p(N)$ for which there are well-known asymptotics. So what I am interested in is some kind of higher-dimensional analogue of counting the number of partitions of an integer.

Does the higher-dimensional version have a name? And have the asymptotics of these higher-dimensional analogues been studied?

(In this question $\mathbb N_0$ is the set $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$.)

They are called $d$-dimensional partitions. One reference (which contains further references) is https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.14397.

Thank you very much @RichardStanley.
